# Solving for many points in a curve at the same time

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose there is a well-behaving monotonic function $f(x)$ where do not have analytical form of $f'(x)$, and we need to solve for many points on this function at once, that is, we need to know the set of $x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_n$ that satisfies $f(x_1) = y_1$, $f(x_2) = y_2$ ... $f(x_n) = y_n$. Is there a way to make the solution process more efficient than just solving each problem individually?

For my problem n is about 10, and each functional evaluation takes about 400 milliseconds. The ys are somewhat evenly spaced.

f is a blackbox function to me and therefore I do not have its analytical form.

It also has a huge overhead cost, and as a result, it is designed to be able to output multiple results at once, at a much more efficient speed. For example, $f$ can take in the vector $(x_1, x_2, ...x_9)$  and output $(y_1, y_2, ... y_9)$ all at once. While calculating $f(x_1)$ takes 0.47 seconds, calculating $f(x_1, x_2, ...x_9)$ only takes 1.3 seconds. This is the property I wish to take advantage of.

Below is an example of what the function looks like.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what $f$ is?

Comment: Nope. I do not have the analytical form of that either.

Comment: Do you have any additional properties of f?

Comment: Do you have any idea about $f$? For instance, is it an increasing function etc?

Comment: Yeah it is monotonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is fairly well behaved, and it is known that there will be solutions for all of the $y_i$, then there is a method which is efficient under the assumption that a function evaluation is very expensive compared to evaluation of a degree-$n-1$ polynomial:

Start with some guess $\{x_i^{(0)}\}$ as to all the points.

Then iteratively, map $\{x_i^{(k)}\}$ into $\{x_i^{(k+1)}\}$ as follows:

- Evaluate all the $z_i = f(x_i^{(k)})$.
- Form an $n-1$-th degree interpolating polynomial $P^{(k)}(x)$ such that 
  $\forall i: P^{(k)}(x_i^{(k)})=z_i$. This can easily be formed, for example, by summing  $\sum R_i Q_i(x)$ where $Q_i(x) = \prod_{j\neq i} (x-x_j)$ and $R_i = Q_i(x_i)$.
- Solve for the roots of  $P(x) = 0$ using Newton's method to get any one root, followed by synthetic division to lower the degree of the polynomial, and repeating.
- Set the $\{x_i^{(k+1)}\}$ to those roots.

This method will be vulnerable to the usual issues of high-order polynomial interpolation, and for some $f(x)$ these might overwhelm the excellent convergence of Newton's method once one gets close to a root. Therefore,
as a slight refinement, one can use the previously computed values of $f(x)$ for lower values of $k$, so as to work with a set of points closer to each eventual $\{x_i^{(k)}\}$. And the behavior might be improved numerically by restricting yourself to slightly lower-degree polynomials based on some set of nearest evaluation points.

Comment: This is certainly a great idea! It fits the property of my function perfectly!